# Need clarification on grammar and correct use of the shop word

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to fill the meta tag description. The difficulty is that Google sets a limit on the maximum number of characters or keywords which allowed.

> Buy Marshall Mode EQ headphones online from a gadget store in bulk and wholesale with PayPal at low prices in USA and Europe. Marshall Mode EQ description, characteristics, reviews.

Is it allowed to use the words "shop" or "store" in relation to online sales? Does this word imply that the store should be located physically?

Answer (score 1):

Shop or Store can be used both of a physical building or a website that sells things. Lots of the language for shops has carried over to the online world. So we talk of an "online shopfront", for example, to mean the top page of an e-commerce site, even though it is not at the "front" of anything.

Similarly, we use familiar metaphors like a "shopping basket". It helps users understand what they are doing when they click on an item. There is no implication that a "shop" should be physically located somewhere.

The word "store" is slightly more common in American English than British, where "shop" is more common.

Comment: In AmE, although both "online shop" and "online storefront" are common enough,  it would be unusual to say "online shopfront".